# CSS drop down failing

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a basic layout here, I am trying to apply a CSS drop down menu to it.

http://www.danielkcheung.com/dan/

As you can see when you go to pick a drop down option the menu doesn't work. I haven't bothered styling it yet as I don't think there's a point till it's functional.

Is there a reason for this? It's as if it's all sitting under the other content.

Comment: in FF, the dropdown works fine, however it does overlap the wordpress post title

Comment: The secondary UL appears for me on hover (Firefox 3.6 ,OSX).

Comment: @Damien, @benhowdle89, I think @Phill means that the drop-down appears okay, it's when you try and click on the sub-menu that the problem appears (in that the menu disappears once the mouse leaves the parent `li` item).

Comment: Ok, he stated that very unclear then. Solution: reset margin and provide padding to the secondary UL so the anchor stays in it's hover state.

Comment: give relevant elements a background-color so you can see where the margin/padding issues are.

Comment: I tried both suggestions but I can't seem to get it to work. By the secondary UL you mean UL LI UL right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest fix is to add this to your `<ul>`: `position: relative; z-index: 1`.

I tested in Firefox only.

If you would like more explanation as to why this works, let me know.

---

A better way is to remove `position: relative` from `#posts` and `#title`.

Just remove `position: relative` from everything unless you're certain it needs it.